# Load a webview in the background

Tags: uiwebview, tabbar, appdelegate

I have a tab bar application and when it starts up there are web views on different tab bars. The app needs speed so when someone opens and it loads onto the first tab bar I need the other web views in the background to load when the application starts. One of my UIWebView's is named twitter and it is on the 'SecondViewController'. I assume the code is in the appDelegate, help is much appreciated in a basic form for my knowledge isn't great.

Answer (score 2):

UIWebViews can't be rendered offscreen.  The best you can do is cache an image of the content the last time it was accessed and present that, then load the web view and cross fade between the two.

Comment: OK, may I ask how I can do this?

Comment: Use UIGraphicsBeginImageContext (or one of it's variants) to render the webview into an image context.  Then get the image from the context and scale/resize to fit your needs.

Comment: aha thanks, but I mean how do I programmatically actually do this?